# B1 Print and Delivery Conditional Action Current User

Tags: sapb1

I've got a piece of code here that should be working but is not, and for the life of me I have no idea why or a better way to go about it.

What I am trying to achieve is having B1 print and delivery determine who the current user is when emailing an A/R invoice, if its X user then it will send the email directly, if it's any other user then it will save as draft + preview. Below is my current code.

```
DECLARE @GetUser AS nvarchar(12)
SET @GetUser = (Select top 1 T1.U_NAME from USR5 T0 INNER JOIN OUSR T1 ON T0.UserCode = T1.USER_CODE where SessionID =@@spid order by Date desc,Time desc)
IF(@GetUser = 'NickJ') 
BEGIN
SELECT 'noDraft' FOR BROWSE
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT 'draft' FOR BROWSE
END
```

When I run that select statement in SAP B1 query generator it shows me NickJ, so I know it works. However boyum and print and delivery seem to not like this query. When I click the email button its not detecting that NickJ is the current user and will instead do the ELSE action.

I also noticed that $[USERNAME] won't work in this conditional or report action.

Does anyone know of a better way of getting the current logged in user for this?

Comment: Hi Nick, Could you use $[USER] (the internal_K field)  to get the correct OUSR row?

Comment: Hi sawsine, had no luck with that either

Answer (score 0):

Just base everything of a SQL Query with a CASE selection like below.
Do not use Procedure...do not use C# or VB script. Use only the DocKey@ Parameter coz thats the most common parameter used in most layouts. Just my observation to get it work. Bit late but posting for future reference. Hope ur issue is resolved by now.

This syntax is B1 HANA

Select case OINV."DocType" when 'I' then 'Items' else 'Service' end DocType
from OINV where  OINV."DocEntry" =  DocKey@